# Linux Mint upgrade to 19 Tara results in desktop panel problems

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade

I upgraded my system recently from Linux Mint 18.3 to Linux Mint 19. Problems resulted: No icons at right in the bottom panel, could not add some items like sound setting, WiFi/network, and others.

Also, the file /etc/apt/sources.list is empty.

How do I edit that bottom panel? Should /etc/apt/sources.list be empty?